# Single click not working on javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a video website, when user clicks on a picture related video runs. But the problem is that first time a user have to double click on a link, after that single click works.

Here's html:

```
<div id="player_container">
    <video controls="controls" id="videoclip" autoplay>
        <source id="mp4video" src="videos\video.mp4" type="video/mp4"   />
        <source id="oggSource" src="video.mp4" type="video/ogg">
        <p> Your browser does not support the video tag <p>
    </video>

    <div class="vid_container_row2">
        <div class="shadow2">
            <div>
                <a href="#" onclick="myFunctionId(this.id);" id="videolink1">
                    <img class="top" src="images/gayle1.jpg" height="80px" width="110px">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shadow2">
            <div>
                <a href="#" onclick="myFunctionId(this.id);" id="videolink2">
                    <img class="top" src="images/rohit-sharma.jpg" height="80px" width="110px">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="shadow2">
            <div>
                <a href="#" onclick="myFunctionId(this.id);" id="videolink3">
                    <img class="top" src="images/blara.jpg" height="80px" width="110px">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunctionId(id){
        var jungi = id;
        if (jungi == "videolink1")
        {
            var videocontainer = document.getElementById('videoclip');
            var videosource = document.getElementById('mp4video');
            var videobutton = document.getElementById('videolink1');
            var newmp4 = 'videos/video.mp4';
            videobutton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                videocontainer.pause();
                videosource.setAttribute('src', newmp4);
                videocontainer.load();
                videocontainer.play();
            }, false);
        }
        else if (jungi == "videolink2")
        {
            var videocontainer = document.getElementById('videoclip');
            var videosource = document.getElementById('mp4video');
            var videobutton = document.getElementById('videolink2');
            var newmp4 = 'second_video.mp4';
            videobutton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                videocontainer.pause();
                videosource.setAttribute('src', newmp4);
                videocontainer.load();
                videocontainer.play();
            }, false);
        }
        else
        {
            var videocontainer = document.getElementById('videoclip');
            var videosource = document.getElementById('mp4video');
            var videobutton = document.getElementById('videolink3');
            var newmp4 = 'third_video.mp4';
            videobutton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                videocontainer.pause();
                videosource.setAttribute('src', newmp4);
                videocontainer.load();
                videocontainer.play();
            }, false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Holy shit using some tabs would not be a bad idea, your javascript is nearly intelligible. It really does make it easier to see where a block begins and ends if you indent it, and you code is much easier to debug that way.

Comment: Your issue is that you have an onclick event in your HTML which then adds an event listener to the videobutton, so the first time you click it, you did not trigger the event, in a double click the second click triggers it, and every time after. There is a much bigger issue here, in that you are adding listeners all over the place. Add them once and forget it!

Answer (score 0):

When you click the link

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunctionId(this.id);" id="videolink3">
```

You are executing the function that *adds a click handler to the element*. To now activate this click, you will have to click it *again*. To add the event listeners on load, remove the `onclick` attributes from your elements and simply pre-apply the function to your DOM like this:

```
var videobutton1 = document.getElementById('videolink1');
var videobutton2 = document.getElementById('videolink1');
var videobutton3 = document.getElementById('videolink1');
[videobutton1, videobutton2, videobutton3].forEach(function(button){
    myFunctionId( button.id )
});
```

It's a bit of a roundabout way (you should not have to find by id and then pass the id, you could just pass the elements around), but it works.

A potentially better way is to structure your dom a little better. here is an example:

```js
var videoPath = document.querySelector('h1'); // This is for debugging on Stack Overflow - there are no videos here so nothing will display. We will change this value to show it is working.

var video = document.querySelector('video'); // get the main video element
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.changeVideoSource'); // get all links marked with the class changeVideoSource

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent following the link
    video.src = this.getAttribute('href'); // set the source
    videoPath.textContent = this.getAttribute('href'); // show the update as the videos are not available here
    video.play(); // Although your video hasn't loaded yet, the system will actually try to start playing as soon as it can.
  })
}
```

```css
video { width: 100%; height: 200px; background: #000; }
```

```html
<a href="video1.mp4" class="changeVideoSource">Video 1</a>
<a href="video2.mp4" class="changeVideoSource">Video 2</a>
<a href="video3.mp4" class="changeVideoSource">Video 2</a>

<h1>video1.mp4</h1>

<video src="video1.mp4"></video>
```

This is much simpeler, and adding another video link is now super easy! Also, as an added bonus, people with disabled javascript *still have access to the videos* as the link will now just be followed.

Comment: Hey again ... thanks for your help ... Can I add a video views counter here without database.... ???

Comment: @Jahangir I think video views counter really does not relate to the above code. You would probably need a database, although you could use something like `localStorage`, but that meas that data isn't really useful to anyone but the person on whose device this is stored. If you want to save data and display it to another user, you will need a database. Otherwise, you can count viewcounts by using something like `video.addEventListener('ended', event => count++)`, where the variable `count` contains a number starting at 0...

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick response dear ... I am really thankful

Comment: Hi ... Now I have a database in mysql named "video" with a single table named "videos". Now I want when a user play a video the column of "videos" increment itself with 1 and shows the total views ... can you please help me? I am searching the web since one week but useless.

Comment: Posting it to a database usually means that you have to `POST` the data to a PHP script, which will then send a ping to your mysql to increase the number. This is far outside the scope of this question, and you might want to post whatever you tried as a new question and get help from people more into databases than I am (or people who love JS usually are).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ... I am really grateful

Answer (score 0):

video.load() starts the loading process, but returns before the video is loaded, and hence the play immediately following it doesn't work as it isn't loaded yet.  You need to use :

```
video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
   // Video is loaded and can be played
}, false);
```

Comment: I don't think this is true (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play ) - a promise is returned and will be rejected if something goes wrong, but it will most likely wait and play as soon as it can now. So the promises' success will start the video, with or without delay.

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp)  
The promise is not standard.  Also, if it returns a promise then the load() would return immediately and you would need to put the play in the success handler of the promise.  You don't want to wait for the full video to load, you want to wait until enough of it has loaded to play, So the canplaythrough event is the one you want.

Comment: I'll be honest, never had an issue with `play()` itself, regardless of loading. It may stutter though, it _is_ better to use the event, but it muddles the question and does not solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score -1):

For one section:

```
var videocontainer = document.getElementById('videoclip');
var videobutton = document.getElementById('videolink3');
var newmp4 = 'third_video.mp4';
videobutton.onclick = null;
videocontainer.src = newmp4;
videocontainer.load();
videocontainer.oncanplay = function (e) {
videocontainer.play();
}
videobutton.onclick = function (e) {
myFunctionId(id);
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue (you still have to click twice for it to work).  `onclick` might be useful, but is is better to use events as you can add multiple event listeners and more easily control them. This is not ot recommended.

Comment: So what? It '_works_' but it teaches bad practise and is not advised. If I told you the best way to get an ice cream is to use an airplane to get to the ice cream truck, then you will be spending a lot of money on air travel while there are many better ways (say, legs) that even allow you to abort your journey halfway through, and save you loads of time and money. Also, **it does not solve the double click problem**.

Comment: It is the easiest way. Why to buy ice cream for 20 dollars if it is possible to buy for 15 dollars in other place?

Comment: **It does not solve the doubleclick problem** and _it teaches bad practise_. Yes, right now it might be 'cheaper' (to use the botched metaphor) but once things get more complex, this system will break and the OP will be stuck with knowledge that does not help him be a more efficient programmer.

Comment: Just try and then write that my method doesn't work.

Comment: **It does not solve the double click problem as you attach an event handler _after_ you clicked**. Also, I have _never_ said 'it does not work', I said 'it is bad practise'. Unless your argument is 'Its good practise because...' you have to put up and move on. Also, already pre-empting you here, 'It's good practise because it works' is _not_ a valid argument for 'good practise'.

Comment: Lets talk when you actually read what I wrote, as this is hopeless.